# How does data binding work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I'm in the process now of trying to add data into a listBox. If you look at my XAML this is my listBox that I have constructed:

```
<ListBox 
            Height="517" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="12,84,0,0" 
            Name="searchList" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="438" 
            SelectionChanged="SearchList_SelectedEvent">

            <!-- What each listbox item will look like -->
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding firstName}" FontSize="28" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastName}" FontSize="28" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

And in my .css class that is associated with the screen containing the listBox:

```
public Search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //The variables that I want to render in the list         
        string firstName = "John";
        string lastName = "Smith";
    }
```

So my question is, how exactly does data binding work? You can see that in the XAML I've attempted to Bind the variables but I have no clue whether that will work or if I'm doing it correctly?

For starters, how does the XAML know where to find those variables??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you go through [this tutorial](http://jesseliberty.com/2010/11/10/windows-phone-from-scratch-6-data-binding-really/) suggested by Tomas Jansson in another answer.
Apart from that in your code,

First you need to create a List or ObservableCollection which contains the data, which is bindable to the ListBox.

```
List myList = new List()
          {new Name() { firstName = "sdfjsdk", lastName= "sdfsfsjdf"},
           new Name() { firstName = "bthbbh", lastName= "ereyyyu"},
           new Name() { firstName = "svbfbb", lastName= "sdfertbn"} };
```

where Name is

```
class Name()
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
}
```

and then in code behind,

```
myList.ItemsSource = myList; //this lets the XAML from where to fetch the data to bind
```

Comment: Okay it's alot clearer now, so basically you just set the listBox.ItemsSource() to some other object that then contains the firstName and lastName etc. And then the listBox automatically gets populated with the data, I don't have to iterate through a for loop or anything like that to populate the list?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use any kind of iteration

Comment: Do you have that tutorial handy?

Comment: @CodoSapien Check it [HERE](http://jesseliberty.com/2010/11/10/windows-phone-from-scratch-6-data-binding-really/)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that your current code won't work.

Each control exists in something known as the logical tree. The logical tree is a tree like hierarchy of controls with your ListBox being the root in this example - and the controls within it the children.

e.g.

```
RootControl
|
|---| ChildOfRootControl
    |
    |----| ChildOfChildOfRootControl
    |    |
    |    | AnotherChildOfChildOfRootControl
    |
    | AnotherChildOfRootControl
```

Each control has a DataContext property - this property is automatically propagated down the tree from the root to all the children (e.g. if you set the DataContext on any control all the control's children will see this DataContext - this is with the exception of anything that derives from `ItemsControl` in which the children usually have the DataContext of the bound `ItemsSource` property). This DataContext only goes down the tree to the children - if you place a new value into the DataContext of a child control, it will override the parents DataContext

The DataContext is the default object that your controls will bind to: i.e. if you don't specify any additional parameters in your binding, the DataContext will be the target object

```
Text="{Binding FirstName}"
```

The above binding looks at the DataContext. In order to bind to something else you need to specify the Source or ElementName in your binding etc

In additional to the DataContext, there is a base control called ItemsControl which most list-like controls will inherit from.

ItemsControl exposes a property called ItemsSource which specifies the list of items that will appear in the control. This works a little differently from DataContext in that you can have both a DataContext and an ItemsSource at the same time.

Additionally, any child items in an ItemsControl (e.g. each listbox item) will not inherit the DataContext from their parent controls, instead their DataContext will point to the item they are individually bound to.

Example - assuming you assigned a DataContext of 'MyObject' to the root control (a grid), and assigned 'MyListOfObjects' to the ListBox:

```
Grid (DataContext = MyObject)
|
|---| ListBox (DataContext = MyObject) (ItemsSource = MyListOfObjects)
    |
    |----| ListBoxItem (DataContext = MyListOfObjects[0])
    |    |
    |    | ListBoxItem (DataContext = MyListOfObjects[1])
    |    |
    |    | ListBoxItem (DataContext = MyListOfObjects[2])
    |    |
    |    | ListBoxItem (DataContext = MyListOfObjects[3])
    |
    | TextBox (DataContext = MyObject)
```

In your case the ListBox.ItemsSource property will be NULL, so your binding paths won't work. When you run this code you will most likely see binding expression errors in the output window as the binding will evaluate to non-existent properties (in fact in this case you won't as there are no items created from ItemsSource)

Usually you bind to an object - such as a business object, or even to other controls on the page.

So in your case you probably want to create an object which houses the FirstName and LastName properties. It also seems like since you are using a ListBox that you need a collection of these items to bind - so ideally you want a collection that implements some kind of change notification mechanism. This ensures that the UI gets updated when the list changes.

ObservableCollection implements this - so creating an ObservableCollection and assigning it to ItemsSource on the ListBox should work.

It might also be worth noting that change notification on ObservableCollection only happens at the list level - (if the list is changed, an item added for instance) but does not happen at the object level. If you also want changes on the objects contained in the list to reflect in the UI then you need to implement change notification on these objects. This is done by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Finally - if you want to be able to edit a binding, make sure you specify this in the binding - Silverlight by default assumes all bindings are read-only. I'm not sure what Windows Phone 7 does, but it may be that you need to specify **Mode** in your bindings

e.g.

```
Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: *"if you set the DataContext on the ListBox, all the listboxes children will see this DataContext"* I know what you're trying to say there, but it's wrong.  The children of the listbox have their data context set to individual items found within the collection bound to the listbox's ItemsSource property.  It would be more correct to say "if you set the DataContext on a Grid, all children of the Grid will have this DataContext"

Comment: Yes you are right, think I was just trying to explain how the data context works and picked a bad control example (e.g. anything but an `ItemsControl` would have been better as you've said)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to search for it? This hopefully explains a lot of how data binding works: http://jesseliberty.com/2010/11/10/windows-phone-from-scratch-6-data-binding-really/

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. Unless you are going to explain the solution here and use the link as a resource - this would be better off as a comment.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson - Thanks nonetheless Tomas, it did make things alot clearer to me though.