# How to access specific cells in datagridrow wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid where i use a foreach(DataGridRow gvr in myDataGrid) and I need to be able to take the info from specific cells in the row and put them into their respective class properties i.e.(a.MessageName = gvr.column["MessageName"].value.ToString()).  But I haven't figured out how to get at the info based on the column.  Here's what i have so far...

```
    foreach (DataGridRow gvr in dgAnnouncement.Items)
    {
         Announcement a = new Announcement();

         a.MessageName = gvr.Column["MessageName"].Value.ToString();
         a.Message = gvr.Column["Message"].Value.ToString();
     }
```

And here's my XAML...

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="631" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Margin="12,124,0,0" Name="dgAnnouncement" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="976" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MessageName"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

After searching the web I still havent found a solution that works for me so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Considered using binding instead? You already have an itemssource - why not walk through the itemssource instead of the rows? Are the columns those that the user must fill?

Comment: Just curious, what is the grid bound to? It looks like your columns don't have any binding expressions - what's the goal and whats the source data?

Comment: To be honest this is my first experience with WPF so i have don't know how to work with ItemSource or walk through it...The columns are user filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it sounds like you want to have a bound list of items that the user can add to and fill in values on

If you want to do this, the best way is via binding on your columns:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="631" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Margin="12,124,0,0" Name="dgAnnouncement" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="976" > 
    <DataGrid.Columns> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MessageName" Binding="{Binding MessageName, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn> 
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

The question is - what do you have ItemsSource set to at the moment?

Ideally this should be a strongly typed collection of `Appointment` objects (`ObservableCollection<Appointment>` maybe). Do you want the users to be able to add new rows? If so you need to either provide a button which performs the `Add` on the source collection or let the datagrid do it (I think it supports an 'empty row' where you can type values... though I usually use Telerik's RadGridView). Generally when you have a grid that has an empty row for the user to add a new value, the grid will look at the underlying collection that's bound and call the appropriate method to add an item. If this collection doesn't support an `Add` method (such as IBindingList does) I think the default is to create a new item using the parameterless constructor for the type (not too sure on this, might be worth doing some reading)

Basically, by binding these properties `TwoWay` it means that each item in the list can be edited by the user directly in the grid. If the user changes a property, that property on the underlying object will be affected*. This means you don't need to write any code to wire this all up. Binding can also be done from control->control so for instance you can bind another grids `ItemsSource` to the `SelectedItems` property on your first grid, and it will automatically update with which items you have selected.

Check out my answer here for more info on DataBinding

[How does data binding work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392971/how-does-data-binding-work/11393609#11393609)

Edit:

- I might add that any changes to the underlying object without going through the grid will still show up in the grid but only if the object implements a property changed notification mechanism e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged` (in System.ComponentModel namespace)