# C# auto declare variables?

Tags: c#, xaml

```
Contacts.Add(new Contact 
{ 
    FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text, 
    LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text, 
    AvatarPath = avatar 
});
```

and In xaml:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" Margin="0,0,5,0" />

 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LastName}" />

 <Image Source="{x:Bind AvatarPath}" Width="100" Height="100" />
```

My code run perfecly fine but why is it running?

Is `{x:Bind FirstName}` auto define a variable `FirstName`?? and I dont even need to set a `Name` profile for the `TextBlock`?

Comment: wpf? xamarin? uwp? windows phone? what is the xaml used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using databinding:

- Your XamlView somehwere gets set a `DataContext` or gets it from its parent.
- Your DataContext contains this `Contacts` variable that you set with the data from your *other* `FirstNameTextBox`/ `LastNameTextBox` and `avatar` .
- Your view binds to the content of the variables in your model.

You are sure that is *your* code?

Read more here:

- [Data Binding - A Better Way to Implement Data Binding in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736453.aspx)
- [How does data binding work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392971/how-does-data-binding-work) (go through the answers and the links provided)

---

This:

```
Contacts.Add(
    new Contact { FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text, 
                  LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text, 
                  AvatarPath = avatar });
```

is probably used as ItemSource/DataContext in for the Xaml you provided.

The Xaml binds to the values inside *each* `Contact` inside the `Contatcs`-list.

Comment: no this is not my code, just tutorial online learing and I just follow along, and yesd I do realize I dont need to set a name for those TextBlock